# Type independent vector class member

Tags: c++, matlab, c++11, vector

I try to build a data structure for (simplified) Matlab v4 Matrices. These Matrices have the following structure:

- a header containing 5 `int32_t`variables which determine the size and content of the Matix.
- a `char[]` array containing the name
- and one (or two if imaginary content) 2D vector(s) `std::vector<std::vector<type>>` of the type specified in the header (`int32_t`, `float64_t` e.g.)

Is there a way to generalize the type? I tried using a factory and a wrapper around the vectors, but due to the single dispatch restriction of virtual functions (no templating allowed) this did not work.

If I try to google a solution, I end up with problems around a polymorphic container, but that's not what I want... after the header is set, the type remains the same.

I'm relatively fresh to C++, so there may be some simple techniques to solve this, but at the moment I have no idea.

best regards

---

**Edit**

As requested I will try to explain my intentions more detailed.

A matlab matrix has the following structure:

1. The Header 5 x 4 Bytes specifying the content

   - a M0PT value containing: `FloatLayout * 1000 + NumericType * 10 + MatrixType` -- Here Floatlayout specifies endianness, NumericType holds the type of the matrix content and the MatrixType can be [ full , sparse,  or text ] i only consider Full at the moment.
   - `mrows` the number of rows
   - `ncols` the number of columns
   - `imagflag` is there an imaginary part [0,1]
   - `namelength +1`
2. The name in `namelength` Bytes as `char`
3. `mrows * ncols` elements of NumericType specified in the header

I hope this helps, i will clarify what I tried in a moment

Comment: what do you mean by generalizing? What exactly would you like to achieve?

Comment: Are the matrices "jagged"?  Ie, can you have one row with 3 elements, the next with 2, the next with 4?  Because that is what you described above.  Does the name have a maximum length?  What is the relationship between the int variables and the size/content of the matrix?  Do you have access to `boost` or the like?  A variable that can be of more than one type is polymorphic: there is more than one way to implement polymorphism.

Comment: in the best case i would like to call a function on the matrix `m.setRealVector(vec)` same for getRealVector - This could be templated functions

Comment: @Yakk no the size is defined by the header, mrows x ncols... so i have a row for each vector

Comment: `vector` is a specific data type in C++ that is not the same as the mathematical concept.  When you use it, please specify explicitly which one you are using.  :)  I have edited in more questions above, please answer them as well.

Comment: Why can't you just define it with a template type T which is the type of the underlying element?   Show what you tried and explain what you need to do that doesn't work with that setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes you don't want to have to store pointers to an interface that handles every case, and instead work directly with the types in question.

```
template<class...>struct types {};
using matlab_types = types<int32_t, float64_t>; // etc

namespace details {
  template<class types, template<class...>class target>
  struct apply_types {};
  template<class...Ts, template<class...>class target>
  struct apply_types<types<Ts...>, target> {
    using type = target<Ts...>;
  };
}
template<class types, template<class...>class target>
using apply_types = typename details::apply_types<types, target>::type;


struct matlab_matrix {
  int32_t a,b,c,d,e; // todo: give better names, defaults, etc
  std::string name; // rather than a fixed size array
  template<class...Ts>
  using data_t = boost::variant< std::vector<Ts>... >;
  apply_types<matlab_types, data_t> data;
};
```

at this point, `data` is a type-safe union of `std::vector<int32_t>` and `std::vector<float32_t>`.

I am using flat arrays (and not vectors of vectors) because vectors of vectors are for "jagged" storage: a contiguous 2-dimensional array should be stored in one buffer.

You can write an `operator[]` that does the right thing (returns a pointer to the start of the one-dimensional vector in question), as well as an `at(size_t, size_t)` that does size checks.

You'll have to write constructors and deal with `boost::variant`, but this is one of the simplest solutions.

Comment: oh, I have a lot to learn ;) give me some time to understand this! Boost is ok I use it for serial IO and threading... I will report back :)

Comment: Now I get it - Thank you!! this is great!